# Using G1GC garbage collector with spark 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, garbage-collection, g1gc

I am trying to use the G1GC garbage collector for spark job but I get a

```
Error: Invalid argument to --conf: -XX:+UseG1GC
```

I tried using these options but haven't been able to get it working

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.60.20:7077 --conf -XX:+UseG1GC /appdata/bblite-codebase/test.py
```

and

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.60.20:7077 -XX:+UseG1GC /appdata/bblite-codebase/test.py
```

What is the correct way to call a `G1GC` collector from spark?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JVM options should be passed as `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` / `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`, ie.

```
 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can configure garbage collection setting in both driver and executor.

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.60.20:7077 \
 --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" \
 /appdata/bblite-codebase/test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Spark 2.4.3, this will not work for the driver extraJavaOptions, which will produce an error of

```
Conflicting collector combinations in option list; please refer to the release notes for the combinations allowed
```

This is because the default `spark-defaults.conf` includes

```
spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=70
spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions  -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %p' -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

which already includes a GC setting, and setting two GC options causes it to complain with this error.  So you may need:

```
--conf "spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC"
--conf "spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC"
```

and also adding other defaults you'd like to propagate over.

Alternatively, you can edit the defaults in `spark-defaults.conf` to remove the GC defaults for driver/executor and force it to be specified in `extraJavaOptions`, depending on your use cases.